# How to configure the system bar and navigation bar for immersive experience

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, material-design, android-theme

I need to configure the system bar and navigation bar like Google's **Google Pay App.**

*PSB screenshot:*
I have marked the bars with green color.
When we open the google pay app, these bar's color changes to white and it feels like they are part of the app.

Also we can scroll out text/images and display them up in system bar.
The experience is immersive.
I need same design for my app (i.e. transparent/colorless system and navigation bars)

How to achieve this in a proper way without touching any base functionality ?
I read this article: [Enable fullscreen mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#kotlin)
And I also read lot of answers around this area but could not find a solution.

Please advice how to achieve it like google pay app ?
And how I can display my text in system bar when scrolling ?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

this requires min API 23 (maybe i'm wrong) The answer is in the documentation as usual
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge#change-color

briefly: you should edit the themes.xml

```
<!-- values-v29/themes.xml -->
<style name="Theme.MyApp">
  <item name="android:navigationBarColor">
     @android:color/transparent
  </item>

  <!-- Optional: set to transparent if your app is drawing behind the status bar. -->
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">
     @android:color/transparent
  </item>

  <!-- Optional: set the status bar light and content dark. -->
  <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">
    true
  </item>
</style>
```